# Point1.heading(Point2)?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am looking for a function with despair in Google Earth Engine that would give me the direction from point 1 to point 2. The goal is to get the same value that Google Earth Pro gives during a measurement (heading).

Does this function exist, how could I get this measurement?

Comment: Would the function be using Google Earth Engine, or using some other coding language like Python? Is the direction in degrees?

Comment: Hello,
The 2 solutions suit me but I think that a mathematical formula will not be appropriate. Indeed, I also used modelizations according to the algorithms of Vincenty or Karney and the results deviate from the measurements on Google Earth. I think Google Earth takes into account the undulations of the geoid that are not found in oblate spheroid models. But if you have an idea, I'm interested. Ideally, the angle should be in degrees, but it's a detail that I can change. (sorry for the automatic translation ...)

Comment: The shortest line between two points on the Earth surface, is a line with a variable heading. You are looking for the azimuth of the constant rumbh line between two points or the initial azimuth of the shortest line (given by Earth Pro)? I think (but don't know) that the geoid is not taken into account in the heading, but in the ground distance (when Terrain layer is unticked); map distance returns ellipsoidal one.

Comment: Hello,  I did not specify : I search the initial azimuth, identical to that provided by Google Earth Pro. I just found that this value is the same whether the box "relief" is checked or not. The geoid would not be taken into account and yet I do not have the same values ​​through vincenty or Karney. Do you know if Google Earth Pro uses another algorithm ?

Comment: No, but interested to know.

Comment: Terrain layer adds a SRTM dataset and modifies the ground distance from geoid to terrain. But map distance and initial azimuth I always believed that are measured on the ellipsoid.